# Python print and input on same line

Tags: python, input, printing, data-analysis

I am trying to execute this but not able to.

Can someone assist?

```
  teamname1 = print(input((plyer1,' Name of your team? '))
  teamname2 = print(input(plyer2,' Name of your team? '))

  print(teamname1)
  print(teamname2)
```

Comment: `print` returns `None` so you are assigning `None` to `teamname1` and `teamname2`. Remove `print()` around the `input()`s

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

1. the first line contains one parenthesis too many
2. input() takes only one argument, the prompt. If plyer1 is a
   string, you must concatenate it
3. same as in comment: print() does not return anything, and can be
   omitted because the prompt of the input() command is already
   displayed.

You probably need something like this:

```
plyer1 = 'parach'
plyer2 = 'amk'

teamname1 = input(plyer1 + ' Name of your team? ')
teamname2 = input(plyer2 + ' Name of your team? ')

print(teamname1)
print(teamname2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the teamname variables. If you could modify the question/code it would help a lot.

As far as print and input on the same line, I think this might be what you're going for.

```
print("player1" + " " + input("Name of your team: "))
print("player2" + " " + input("name of your team: "))
```

P.S. There are many tutorials on-line that could help. Make sure to look around first, then come here.

Comment: player 1 is a string which I am wanting to print before the question. I can see what i am doing wrong. Thank you for helping out.